# JQuery error under the line. add get id and number, then error sign?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

How to solve jQuery get id and add number??

```js
var sum = 0;
var number = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    number = $('#code_a' + i)[0].innerHTML); 
    //alert(number);
    sum = sum + parseInt(number);
}
return sum;
// alert(sum);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="code_a1">5</tr>
  <tr id="code_a2">9</tr>
  <tr id="code_a3">1</tr>
  <tr id="code_a4">20</tr>
  <tr id="code_a5">10</tr>
</table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKkH8.png)

Comment: You want to get sum of rows?

Comment: yea. with for loop

Comment: Your html is invalid. The `tr` should has `td` or `th` and can't contain direct text in it. First you should valid html.

Comment: this is no problem.

Comment: It is problem. If you check snippet in inspect, text of `tr`s went out of table and `tr`s is empty and you can't get target text from elements using js

Comment: <table>
  <tr id="code_a1">5</tr>
  <tr id="code_a2">9</tr>
  <tr id="code_a3">1</tr>
  <tr id="code_a5">10</tr>
</table> then what is if condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below code:

```js
function returnSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    var number = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        number = $('#code_a' + i)[0].innerHTML;        
        sum += parseInt(number);
    }
    
    return sum;
}

var result = returnSum();
console.log(returnSum());

$("#result").text("Sum is: " + result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
   <tr>
      <td id="code_a1">5</td>
      <td id="code_a2">9</td>
      <td id="code_a3">1</td>
      <td id="code_a4">20</td>
      <td id="code_a5">10</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<div id="result"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace below line for correcting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`:

```
number = $('#code_a' + i)[0].innerHTML);
```

With this:

```
number = $('#code_a' + i)[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Its still not returning the sum but concatenating the numbers

Comment: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined.. this error show

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `<td>` tag to retrieve the content. So try below code,

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
var total =  calculateNumbers();
$('#total').html('Total = ' + total);

})
function calculateNumbers(){
    var sum = 0;
    var number = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= $('td').length-1; i++) {
        number = $('table').find('td').eq(i).html(); 
        sum = sum + parseInt(number);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="code_a1"><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr id="code_a2"><td>9</td></tr>
  <tr id="code_a3"><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr id="code_a4"><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr id="code_a5"><td>10</td></tr>
</table>

<div id=total></div>
```